# Have I missed something in JS?

Tags: javascript

I have a js coding here, but it doesnt work. What is wrong with it?
Am i missing any {}? or what have I written wrong?

```
window.addEventListener("load", showPage);


function showPage()
console.log("showPage");

document.getElementById('horizontal1').style.animation = 'mymoveHor 1s';
document.getElementById('horizontal2').style.animation = 'mymoveHor 0.5s';
document.getElementById('vertical1').style.animation = 'mymoveVer 1.5s';


var dfade = document.getElementById("portfolio1");

function fadeIn(dfade, time) {

    dfade.style.opacity = 0;

    var last = +new Date();
    var tick = function () {
        dfade.style.opacity = +dfade.style.opacity + (new Date() - last) / time;
        last = +new Date();

        if (+dfade.style.opacity < 1) {
            (window.requestAnimationFrame && requestAnimationFrame(tick)) || setTimeout(tick, 16);
        }
    };

    tick();
}

fadeIn(dfade, 3000);
```

please help me out...

Comment: what error are you getting in the console? add the error to the question. Your function has no opening brackets as a start, it should be function name(){

Comment: did you use opening and closing curly braces {} for function showPage()?

Answer (score 1):

Just add "{" and "}" to your showPage function

```
function showPage() {
  console.log("showPage");

  document.getElementById('horizontal1').style.animation = 'mymoveHor 1s';
  document.getElementById('horizontal2').style.animation = 'mymoveHor 0.5s';
  document.getElementById('vertical1').style.animation = 'mymoveVer 1.5s';
}

function fadeIn(time) {
    var dfade = document.getElementById("portfolio1");

    dfade.style.opacity = 0;

    var last = +new Date();
    var tick = function () {
        dfade.style.opacity = +dfade.style.opacity + (new Date() - last) / time;
        last = +new Date();

        if (+dfade.style.opacity < 1) {
            (window.requestAnimationFrame && requestAnimationFrame(tick)) || setTimeout(tick, 16);
        }
    };

    tick();
}

window.addEventListener("load", showPage);

fadeIn(dfade, 3000);
```

Comment: Hi, could you please show me exactly... Im a bit lost in this js-world... :S